# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error' what(): basic_string::_S_create

Tags: c++, string, stl, segmentation-fault

I am getting runtime error mentioned in the title when compiler is in release version and segfault when it is in debug version. I did some research and all I found that it is because of the way I am passing strings to add method. I am not clear so it would great help if anyone describe in simple words why runtime error is occurring.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
string add(string a,string b)
{

int lena=a.size()-1,lenb=b.size()-1,carry=0,t;
//segfault occurs here 
string tmp;
int m,n;
while(lena>=0||lenb>=0)
{
    m=0;
    n=0;
    if(lena>=0)
    {
        m=a[lena]-'0';
        lena--;
    }
    if(lenb>=0)
    {
        n=b[lenb]-'0';
        lenb--;
    }
    t=m+n+carry;
    if(t>9)
    {
        carry=1;
    }
    else
    carry=0;
    tmp.push_back('0'+t%10);
}
if(carry)
tmp.push_back('1');
reverse(tmp.begin(),tmp.end());
return tmp;}

class Solution
{
public:
string multiply(string A,string B);
};

string Solution::multiply(string A,string B) {
    int i=A.size()-1,j=0,szb=B.size(),c=0,m=0,k=0,n=0;
    string sum="",tmp="";
    while(i>=0)
    {
        tmp.clear();
        j=szb-1;
        k=n;
        while(k--)
        {
            tmp.push_back('0');
        }
        n++;
        c=0;
        while(j>=0)
        {
            m=(A[i]-'0')*(B[j]-'0')+c;
            c=m/10;
            tmp.push_back((m%10)+'0');
            j--;
        }
        if(c)
        tmp.push_back(c+'0');
        reverse(tmp.begin(),tmp.end());
        sum=add(sum,tmp);
        i--;
    }
    string ans;
    for(i=0,j=sum.size();i<j;i++)
    {
        if(sum[i]!='0')
        {
            while(i<j)
            {
                ans.push_back(sum[i]);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    if(ans.size()==0)
    return "0";
}

int main()
{
    Solution ob;
    string  s;
    s=ob.multiply("99999","99999");
    cout<<s<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is nothing to do with the way you pass strings to the add function. I'm not sure where you got that idea. The error is here

```
if(ans.size()==0)
return "0";
```

it should say

```
if (ans.size() == 0)
    return "0";
else
    return ans;
```

The problem was that if `ans.size() > 0` then you weren't returning anything, but your function promised to return a string. This causes a runtime crash.

When I tried your code on my compiler it gave me a warning

warning C4715: 'Solution::multiply' : not all control paths return a value

which says exactly what I said, you don't always return a value from `multiply`. Your compiler probably says something similar, you should always pay attention to compiler warning messages. They usually do indicate that something is wrong with your code.

Comment: Thanks john. I got my wrong guess when i searched the SO with same error. May be their those cases were different than mine and I misunderstood. I am using codeblocks 13.12 and when I tried line by line debugging every time segfault occurred at the line no I mentioned in the post. Can you please explain why?

Comment: @FarsanRashid I can't explain that. For me the error occurred at the line `s=ob.multiply("99999","99999");` when assigning the result of `multiply` to the variable `s`. That is what I would expect from the error you made.

Comment: Which IDE did you use?

Comment: Visual Studio 2013. It's possible that you have another error which I didn't pick up.